# Spark Catalog w/ AWS Glue: database not found

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, aws-glue

Ive created an EMR cluster with the Glue Data catalog. When I invoke the spark-shell, I am able to successfully list tables stored within a Glue database via

```
spark.catalog.setCurrentDatabase("test")
spark.catalog.listTables
```

However when I submit a job via `spark-submit` I get a fatal error

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Database 'test' does not exist.;
```

I am creating my SparkSession within the job being submitted via `spark-submit` via

```
SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport.getOrCreate
```

Answer (score 17):

Adding the `hive.metastore.client.factory.class` configuration to the code initiating the spark session solved the issue for me:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
...
            .config("hive.metastore.client.factory.class", "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory")
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .getOrCreate();
```

that's the same configuration defined in aws docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-glue.html) and added to the cluster configuration when checking `Use for Hive table metadata` on cluster creation, but for some reason dosn't work as expected (I'm using emr 5.12.0).

Comment: Exactly, this config solved the issue. It is the same as selecting that metadata checkbox in the EMR creation with EC2. Thanks a lot.

Comment: perfect answer for me

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue: `spark-submit` will not discover the AWS Glue libraries, but `spark-shell` working on the master node will.

It turns out that my `spark-submit` job uses a fat `.jar` which was compiled with the standard `org.apache.spark` and `org.apache.hive` libraries. The jar libraries were being used in stead of the custom classes installed on `EMR`.
If this is the case with you, make sure to exclude all:

> 'org.apache.spark:'
>   'org.apache.hive:'
>   'org.apache.hadoop:' modules from you `.jar`

Here is the reference I used for `.Gradle`: http://unethicalblogger.com/2015/07/15/gradle-goodness-excluding-depends-from-shadow.html.

Adding `compileOnly` keyword in front of all spark libraries fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Our issue was IAM permissions on the EMR cluster; make sure that the cluster IAM instance profile has full access to glue.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the option "Use Glue data catalog as the Hive metastore" inside the Glue job; that's fundamental, otherwise Spark won't see the Glue catalog and will only see the "default" Database created by Glue.

Answer (score 0):

My problem ended up being that another classification configuration had been interfering with the `spark-hive-site` one. I deleted all others, and it finally was able to connect.

Answer (score -2):

EMR 5.9.0 has just been released - please give it a shot, it should work for you.

Relevant documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-components.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-glue.html